# Функция для создания вложенных HTML-блоков

Tags: javascript, функции

Хотелось сделать красивую функцию, чтобы можно было одной "цепочкой" вызовов создать и вернуть вложенные HTML-элементы.
 Вызовы функций получились (и вставки работают как надо), а вот как, в самом конце вызовов, сразу вернуть самый первый созданный элемент - вопрос.
 Получается такой ужОс:

```js
let html = nestHTML('div', 111)('div', 222)('div', 333, 'moo')('div', 444);

test.appendChild( html.bubu.parentNode.parentNode.parentNode );

function nestHTML(tag, textContent, className) {
  let elem = document.createElement(tag);
 
  elem.textContent = textContent || ""; 
  elem.className = className || "";
  
  if( nestHTML.bubu ){
    nestHTML.bubu.appendChild(elem);
    nestHTML.bubu = elem;
  } else {
    nestHTML.bubu = elem;
  }

  return nestHTML;
}
```

```css
section div {
  border: 2px solid orange;
  padding: 5px;
}

.moo {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<section id="test"></section>
```

А хотелось бы в главный appendChild передать что-то покороче.

(можно было сделать одну функцию с аргументом-массивом, но тут в том числе и спортивный интерес).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый простой вариант – сохранить самый первый созданный элемент, например в свойство `root`:

```js
let html = nestHTML('div', 111)('div', 222)('div', 333, 'moo')('div', 444);
test.appendChild(html.root);


function nestHTML(tag, textContent, className) {
  function nested(tag, textContent, className) {
    let elem = document.createElement(tag);

    elem.textContent = textContent || "";
    elem.className = className || "";

    if (nested.parent) {
      nested.parent.appendChild(elem);
      nested.parent = elem;
    } else {
      nested.parent = elem;
    }

    return nested;
  }
  nested.root = nested(tag, textContent, className).parent;
  return nested;
}
```

```css
section div {
  border: 2px solid orange;
  padding: 5px;
}

.moo {
  border-color: red;
}
```

```html
<section id="test"></section>
```